# What would happen to a planet at the heliosphere's termination shock?

Tags: planets, solar-wind, interstellar-matter

Assuming that a planet with an atmosphere already existed which orbits at the radius of the termination shock of a star, what would happen to it over time?

As a follow-up, would it be possible for a planet of any kind to form at the termination shock?

Comment: The termination shock only looks sharp because the distance scales are so large. It's actually fairly diffuse on the scale of a planetary diameter, and it's close to a perfect vacuum. It's hard to see how it would have any significant effect on a planet in the vicinity. Note that any planet that far out is going to be very cold, so only a tenuous Pluto-like atmosphere would be present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with John's comment.

The [termination shock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliosphere) was first crossed by the [Voyager 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1) spacecraft, and it lies between ~75-90 [AU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_unit) from the sun.  Thus, at those distances the [solar photon flux](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/sunfact.html) would be reduced by factors of ~5,625-8,100, thus solar power received would only be ~0.17-0.25 $W \ m^{-2}$.

There would be slightly higher levels of [galactic cosmic rays](http://helios.gsfc.nasa.gov/gcr.html), as measured by the Voyager spacecraft.  So a slightly higher radiation dosage, but a [magnetized planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetosphere) with a thick atmosphere would help to mitigate that.

Perhaps the most interesting effect would be what happens to an atmosphere under such conditions.  Most of the gases in our atmosphere would [condense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation) and/or [freeze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing), falling like rain and/or snow (depending on the compound).  Similar things occur at [Pluto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto#Atmosphere), which is only ~30-50 AU from the sun (or ~0.56-1.53 $W \ m^{-2}$ of solar radiation), depending on the period of its orbit.  For instance, [oxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen) freezes (i.e., turns from a liquid to a solid) around 54 K or -$360 \ ^{\circ} F$.  Pluto's surface temperature ranges from ~33-55 K, thus oxygen is probably frozen or in liquid form if present there.  As stated earlier, Pluto is ~33-67% of the distance from the termination shock, thus it receives ~225-900% of the solar radiation observed at the termination shock.

Watching oxygen freeze and fall like snow might be fun, so long as you did not have to breath it...